# Prove that $(x-1,y-1)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb F_2[x,y]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

So I need to show that $\mathbb F_2[x,y]/(x-1,y-1)$ is an integral domain.

If I define a homomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb F_2[x,y]\to\mathbb F_2[x,y]/(x-1,y-1)$ the kernel of the homomorphism is $(x-1,y-1)$. So what's next ? I am clueless.

Comment: If you want to go with that approach, you will want to define a homomorphism from $\Bbb F[x,y]$ to something you know if an integral domain, with kernel $(x-1,y-1)$. The image of that homomorphism will be isomorphic to your quotient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

Consider the ring homomorphism
\begin{align}
\mathbf F_2[x,y]&\longrightarrow \mathbf F_2 ,\\
p(x,y)&\longmapsto p(1,1),
\end{align}
check it is surjective and determine its kernel.

Comment: Its kernel is $(x-1,y-1)$ and it is surjective by the first isomorphism theorem.Am I correct @Bernard.

Comment: The implication is that the ideal is not only prime, it is maximal.

Comment: @Smita: That's right.

Comment: @Bernard: how did you determine that it will be surjective to $F_2$.Suppose I have the ideal as $(x^2,y^2)$ what will be corresponding map and how will you guess it?

Comment: A constant polynomial maps onto what, in your opinion? I don't understand your second question. Could you give more explanations?

Comment: Suppose instead of $(x-1,y-1)$ I have $(x^2,y^2)$ will that be prime and if it is then how will you prove it similar to the proof given by you to my original question.@Bernard

Comment: It is not a prime ideal: in the quotient, $x$ and $y$ are nilpotent.